# how to mail created pdf in php?

Tags: php, pdf

I have to created pdf using jquery and then how to send the created pdf into the controller?

My code to print is

```
<script>
function printTicket(printable) {
    var printContents       = document.getElementById(printable).innerHTML;    
    var originalContents    = document.body.innerHTML;         
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    window.print();    
    $('#email').val(printContents);
}
</script>
<input type = "hidden" name ="post[attachment]"   id="email">
```

Comment: this is your jquery and html - where is the send function in your php?

Comment: `.print()` has nothing to do with PDF. Try using jsPDF lib to create PDF in-memory. Then do Ajax request to server with bas64 encoded content of PDF.